# SQL query to bulk change old domain to new domain in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have recently moved my Wordpress blog from domain A to domain B (just changed domainnames). Everything works well, but I noticed that some images are not showing up. I found that they still reference the old domain A.

When I look in the MySQL database, I can see that these references are in the wp_post table, more in particular in the post_content column.

Which SQL query can I use to change all these links from domain A to domain B. I would need to find the following string in that column

`<a href="http://domainA/...."` and replace with `<a href="http://domainB/..."`

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Query** to update post_content value with new URL.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://domainA/', 'http://domainB/');`

**SQL Query** to update guid value with new URL.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://domainA/','http://domainB/');`

But before doing this you should take a Database backup.

Comment: Just to make sure understand before executing it. The column post_content contains general text (the Wordpress posts). In that text sometimes there will be the string http://domainA/. It is not always there but when it's there it is part of the text. Does this query search that substring in the text field and replace it? Or will it replace the entire column content?

Comment: @wiwa1978: the above SQL query will search the word `domainA` and will replace that with `domainB`, it is just like Find & Replace.